# Should I use 'including' in this sentence?

Tags: lists

I have some question.

Should I use 'including' in this sentence?
Which sentence is better?

> 1. Ability to monitor and configure devices **including** the company's
>      Cisco Systems, workstations and servers using open-source and
>      Microsoft software.
> 2. Ability to monitor and configure: devices the company's Cisco
>      Systems, workstations and servers using open-source and Microsoft
>      software.

P.S.
This is an item in a list.

Comment: Is the colon in the second option where it should be?

Comment: Cisco Systems is not a device but a company name.  Cisco Systems routers perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely first sentence because you are using the colon incorrectly in the second sentence.  Even if you rewrote the second sentence correctly, I'd still prefer the first sentence, though.

Regarding the first sentence, it should have a couple commas added for clarity.  I'd also put "Cisco systems" last otherwise it can sound like you mean "Cisco systems, Cisco workstations, and Cisco servers."

> Ability to monitor and configure devices including the company's workstations, servers, and Cisco systems using open-source and Microsoft software.

---

When you use a colon in the manner above, a list of items is supposed to follow, then the sentence should end.  Putting something after the list (like "using open-source and Microsoft software") makes it sound like that's an item on the list and sounds really confusing.

What you are "listing" is devices, namely:

- the company's Cisco Systems
- [the company's] workstations
- [the company's] servers
- and others (since you were thinking about using the word "including")

and you want to describe the ability to manage *each* of those

- using open-source and Microsoft software

Also, a better word to talk about all that than devices is *resources* - since these are related to IT - *IT resources* is even better.

So, the sentence should be:

> Ability to monitor and configure, using open-source and Microsoft software, the following company IT resources: Workstations, servers, Cisco systems, and others.

Even with the above, I'd prefer the first sentence - because when you list items in the manner above it should be specific things - the above is too general and makes it seem like you don't really know much about the ability in question.